# Determine if cell contains a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a command button named "update" to activate the macro.

The macro should check if in the range G:25 to G:33 the cell is empty.
If empty nothing should happen.
If you write a number into the Box it should copy that number and then put it into a cell on the second worksheet.
So Sheet1.(G:25) should be copied into sheet2.(G14) and then iterate till G:25

Nothing is happening.

Sheet1 = "Übersicht"
Sheet2 = "Semester01"

```
Dim cell As Range, c As Integer, score As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("G25:G33")

c = 14
For Each cell In rng
    score = Cells.Value
    If score < 0 Then
        zelle.Copy
        Sheet2.Cells(7, c).Select
        Worksheet("Semester01").Paste
        c = c + 1
    End If

Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: If it hits a blank and then finds a value is it supposed to skip a line on Sheet2?

Comment: Yes if in the first cell on sheet1 the cell is blank nothing should happen.
So in the second turn it should check the second cell G:26 and if this is blank it should copy the value to sheet2.G15

Comment: Based on your solution, I strongly recommend that you take the time to learn how to debug in VBA https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point for all the extra variables and missing/confusing parent references. I don't see where *zelle* comes from.

```
Option Explicit

sub go()

    Dim cell As Range, c As Integer

    c = 14
    For Each cell In sheet1.Range("G25:G33")
        If val(cell.Value) < 0 Then
            cell.Copy destination:=Sheet2.Cells(7, c)
            c = c + 1
        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

If you use `Option Explicit` you can avoid misspelling variable.

Comment: oh I changed the variables to english ones. Zelle is german for cell must have forgotten one

Comment: still not working, I think I got something else wrong.
The code is written in a private sub on sheet1 because of the command button 
is that a problem ?
or should i rename what you spelled as sheet1 and sheet2 ?

Comment: its working now ! 
wile writing the code here I changed a > into a < so I changed it back in your code too and its perfectly working now 
thank you very much ! 
Greets from Austria

Comment: @Igor - Es ist eine gute Idee "Option Explicit" immer zu benutzen.  Es kann viele Schreibfehlern vermeiden zu helfen, weil man musst explizitlich allen variables declaren.  (Hoffentlich mein Deutsch ist verständlich! :P )

Answer (score 0):

## Copy Cells If Criteria...

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ZelleCopy()

    Const cShS As String = "Übersicht"    ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const cShT As String = "Semester01"   ' Target Worksheet Name
    Const cRng As String = "G25:G33"      ' Source Column Range Address
    Const cTgtFR As Long = 14             ' Target First Row Number
    Const cTgtCol As Variant = "G"        ' Target Column Letter/Number ' or 7

    Dim wsS As Worksheet  ' Source Worksheet
    Dim wsT As Worksheet  ' Target Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range     ' Current Cell (For Each Control Variable)
    Dim c As Long         ' Target Cell (Row) Counter
    Dim Score As Long     ' Criteria Value

    ' Create references to Source and Target Worksheets.
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsS = .Worksheets(cShS)
        Set wsT = .Worksheets(cShT)
    End With

    ' Write Target First Row Number to Target Row Counter.
    c = cTgtFR
    ' Loop through each cell (row) in Source Column Range.
    For Each cell In wsS.Range(cRng)
        ' Write value of Current Cell to Criteria Value.
        Score = cell.Value
        ' Check if Criteria Value is less than 0.
        If Score < 0 Then
            ' Write Criteria Value to current cell in Target Column.
            wsT.Cells(c, cTgtCol) = Score
            ' Count Target Row.
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```